# How to send mail dynamic parameter email in content using Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, sendmail

```
           $url_str = $request->account_name . ".hello.com/";

           $objDemo = new \stdClass();
           $objDemo->firstname = $request->first_name;
           $objDemo->account_name = $request->account_name;
           $objDemo->title = 'Registration Information';
           $objDemo->username = $request->username;
           $objDemo->password = $password;
           $objDemo->url = URL('/');

           $objTmp = new \stdClass();
           $objTmp->firstname = $request->first_name;
           $objTmp->account_name = $request->account_name;
           $objTmp->title = 'Booking Registration Information';
           $objTmp->username = $request->username;
           $objTmp->password = $password;
           $objTmp->url = $url_str;

           Mail::to($request->email)->send(new BookingRegistration($objTmp));
           Mail::to($request->email)->send(new AccountRegistration($objDemo));
```

I have create send mail in Laravel. on objDemo working well. but for ObjTmp not working maybe the parameter $url_str have any "." value make it not working .

Comment: have you seen this in echo or dd `$url_str` what exactly it shows ?

Comment: yes, ex: sub01.hello.com

Comment: Then you might be doing something wrong in `BookingRegistration` here.

Comment: Are you saving the record to `DB` first ? If yes, then you should make it save like `$objDemo->save();` and also `$objTmp->save();` and you also need to use `DB::beginTransaction();` search a bit about it, otherwise you will face problem on some instances.

Comment: No, I have not saving to the database. I just want to show that URL link "sub01.hello.com" in email body and a href button, but that not working and did not show any error.

Comment: show the `view` and `BookingRegistration` code.

Comment: Show codes for both your email view and BookingRegistration.

Comment: [View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3KO4.png [BookingRegistration]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToVXb.png

Comment: for url you have to have an `<a>` try a bit search for url components in laravel mail.